# Import image from javascript to .pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm new to web development and trying to learning how to use javascript and .pug. I have set var camgrounds with image files

```
router.get('/campgrounds', function (req, res) {

var campgrounds = [
    {
        title: "Paynetwon Campground",
        image: img(src ="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/14/17/57/mountains-5298769_960_720.jpg")
    }];
res.render('campground', {
    campgrounds: campgrounds
});
```

});

When I try to go campgrounds render page, i have error message **"img is not defined"**

On my camground.pug, i wrote as:

```
doctype html

each camping in campgrounds


ul
    li= camping.title
    li = camping.image
```

can someone help with this error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.. it was just
img(src=camp.image)

Answer (score 0):

Bankole is right, you should just pass the image path to Pug and let Pug do the rest. However, the correct markup for creating an image in Pug would look like this. (And if you want a list of campgrounds, I'd suggest moving the `ul` element outside the loop as follows:)

```
ul
  each camp in campgrounds
    li
      p= camp.title
      img(src= camp.image)
```

Comment: Thanks.. When i ran the program, i get the crack image... what is that mean? is that mena i get wrong url?

Comment: @junjung Are you also changing your router to just pass the image path?

Comment: yes that is correct.. what i trying to do was save every image and name to js var and when i go to render page which is in .pug, it should be pass through name and image..